# Rails server is stopped after some time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

For some reason the Rails server is stopped after some time without generate any error message neither on the screen nor in the log, Simply it stops and return to os prompt.

I noticed it happens when I visit a view that use ActionText with embedded images.

I use: OS Windows Server 2022 Standard Ruby 3.2.2 (2023-03-30 revision e51014f9c0) [x64-mingw-ucrt] Rails 7.0.8

Comment: Likely a memory leak or some other error -- but impossible to know without logs.

Comment: I noticed it only happens in production environment.  Maybe can be something about images processing (libvips).

Comment: For discarting, I changed the server of deploymentation.  After a day, without apparent reason, the service stopped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not in Rails. The firewall policy was blocking the PostgreSQL server ports, it was doing that Rails server was stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the issue was resolved.

For images processing in production environment, Rails was requering that libvips was installed.  I installed "vips-dev-w64-all-8.14.5.zip" which was causing problems, so I installed "vips-dev-w64-web-8.14.5.zip" and issue was resolved.  Apparently this version has any special thing for web environment.

**Updated:**

No. It was not that.  I have noticed that it doesn't happen when I active "debugger" gem in production section in Rubygem file.

**Updated:**

It took more time to happen, but it happened again.